# How to generate without repeat value in using two random ()

Tags: c, cocos2d-iphone

I am generating random Nos to store my  matrix index for  row and column . That is   different row and column index Nos every time not repeat.   But some time same value is generating.How to rectify this problem.

This is what i written .. for example

4 * 4 Matrix. i am  running with loop and storing date

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<6;i++)
  {

  Row    =     arc4random() % 4 ;
  Column =     arc4random() % 4;

  CGFloat xOffset1 = (block.contentSize.width+350)+((block.contentSize.height-15)*Column);  
  FireBlock.position = ccp(xOffset1,Row*15);

  statement 1--- store Column;
  statement 2--- store Row;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only 16 different combinations, I'd write all of them in an array, shuffle the array, then select from the array.

```
struct row_col_index {
    int row;
    int column;
};

/* ... */
    struct row_col_index all_combinations[4*4] = {
        {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3},
        {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3},
        {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3},
        {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3},
    };

    shuffle(all_combinations);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Row = all_combinations[i].row;
        Column = all_combinations[i].column;
        /* ... */
    }
/* ... */
```

Comment: This is not possible my program, because my code firing game . diff. levels i am generating every level diff matrix . so it will not possible assign value for matrix index

Answer (score 3):

You could maintain an array of booleans that keep track of which elements you've already used.  For instance:

```
int used[16];
memset(&used, 0, sizeof(used));  // All unused to start with

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    // Generate random number
    int r = arc4random() % 16;
    // Keep generating until we've found an unused element
    while (used[r])
    {
        r= arc4random() % 16;
    }
    used[r] = 1;   // Mark as used

    row = r % 4;
    col = r >> 2;

    ...
}
```

Comment: You could explain why you don't need 2 `used` arrays: 1 for rows and another for columns (I know why, but it isn't evident for everybody) :-)

Comment: Its working . But When i using  matrix 8*4 the same modification code is not working.Index row and column is taking 7,10,8 etc. but not 16 row and column index value .anything wrong i implemented . 
Loop 16 is my matrix index max. 

int used[32];
memset(&used, 0, sizeof(used));  // All unused to start with
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    // Generate random number
    int r = arc4random() % 32;
    // Keep generating until we've found an unused element
    while (used[r])
    {
        r= arc4random() % 32;
    }
    used[r] = 1;   // Mark as used
    row = r % 8;
    col = r >> 2;
 ...
}

Comment: Whatever you written  in sample code is working .. 
First i need to clarify above sample ..This is what i understood ..
Used [16] --> 16 is 4*4 =16 matrix value .
 r = arc4random() % 16 --> 16 is max value of matrix again 4*4;
 row = r % 4  -> Max of Row .
 its  correct. Ok . I am asking question again. 
I am implementing cocos2d iphone game firing . There are  many levels . My matrix  also changing every level..

Comment: When i increase row and column  and loop condition ..this will not working .. why?

Comment: 4*4, 8*4 ,10*4,  12*4 ,  14*4, 16*4 ,18*4 ,20*4 ,22*4,24*4 ,26*4 ,28*4, 30*4  And Loop Value also i am creasing like  for different matrix. For   loop is not problem, only random no. i think you got my point .

Comment: 4*4, 8*4 ,10*4,  12*4 ,  14*4, 16*4 ,18*4 ,20*4 ,22*4,24*4 ,26*4 ,28*4, 30*4  And Loop Value also i am increasing   for different matrix. For   loop is not problem, only random no generation . i think you got my point .

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is 4x4, you first have 16 choices of where to place the next entry. Once it's placed you have 15 choices. Once two are placed, 14 choices. Etc. You should adjust your algorithm based on this principle.